# How can I convert timestamps into year?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with this kind of column data.

```
1906-02-20
1906-02-21
```

I want to create separate columns with years, months and days.

Intended output:

```
1906 02 20
1906 02 21
```

I have used things like strptime and lubridate before. But not able to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 format(as.Date('2014-12-31'),'%Y %m %d')
```

(obviously you want to replace `as.Date('2014-12-31')` with your date vector).

`format()` converts dates to stings given the format string provided.  for the individual year, month and date values, you want:

```
myData$year <- format(as.Date('2014-12-31'),'%Y')
#> "2014"
myData$month <- format(as.Date('2014-12-31'),'%m')
#> "12"
myData$day <- format(as.Date('2014-12-31'),'%d')
#> "31"
```

I often refer to [this page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) when I need to look up the meaning of the format strings.

Comment: Thanks. How can I access the individual year, month and day and store it in separate columns?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
X <- data.frame()
X <- rbind(strsplit(x = "1906-02-20", split = "-")[[1]])
colnames(X) <- c("year", "month", "day")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `separate` function in the `tidyr` package

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df, "V1", into = c("year", "month", "day"), sep = "-")
#   year month day
# 1 1906    02  20
# 2 1906    02  21
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
1906-02-20
1906-02-21
")
```

Comment: It's a default column name because you didn't say how your column is called. I've provided the data I used in the answer too